# How to get specific rows in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Say I have a users table which contains 1000's of users! So, how can I grab the users with id starting from 15 to 48, for instance?

Comment: skip and take, eg: skip(15)->take(33), for more detail: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write simple MySQL Query

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id BETWEEN ? AND ?', [15,48]);
```

OR by using an Eloquent model as follow

```
\App\User::whereBetween('id', array(15, 48))->get();
```

Comment: Or database builder: `DB::table('users')->whereBetween('id', [15, 48])->get()`